# SharePoint : Query list items added/ updated after user's last visit

Tags: sharepoint, list

We need to fetch the items added/updated after the user's last visit.
We need this information from 3 separate lists under the same web. 
Pointers on how to accomplish this would be very helpful (and does SharePoint provide any API for this).

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

Filtering by modified date is straightforward enough, though the method will depend on the type of view - the tricky part is getting the last login time - you're probably going to need a bit of custom code to save that.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force would be to run a foreach on every version until you reach a version before the users last login date, and do this on every list item, and then again on every list. You can see which fields changed this way by seeing what changed between versions. You can narrow down the the set of items to do this on by only querying for ones with a modified date since the users last login

As for finding the users last login, sorry I can suggest anything for that. I've not looked for it before.